# how to run a robot framework script with python 3.7 from the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, robotframework

I want to run my robot framework script through the command line terminal on macOS which by default runs on python 2.7 however my IDE is set to interpret my scripts using python 3.7 and therefore my PYTHONPATH is set to use 3.7 too and this enables me to locate my custom libraries

how would I run my robot script through the terminal using 3.7? my current command is simply:

```
robot -d Results myScript.robot
```

the test work fine when ran through the terminal within my IDE so I'm pretty sure that this is my only issue

Comment: having run the command python3 robot -d Results myScript.robot I recieve the following error can't open file 'robot': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: try `python -m robot`, as described in the user guide here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-installed-robot-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python3 -m robot -d Results myScript.robot
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting this error "can't open file 'robot'" with command python3 robot -d Results myScript.robot because you might not be the test directory in your cmd.

Steps-> Go to project root directory-> Run the Command with Python3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create virtualenv with python3: `python3 -mvenv venv`
2. Activate it: `call venv/bin/activate`
3. install robot and required libs *after* you have activated the venv.
4. call robot as usual.

And everytime you are in shell, where that particular venv is not activated, you need to repeat the step 2 again ..